# SSH: Permission Denied (publickey,password)

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

new to cybersecurity bear w/me. Just a learning situation is all, to progress onwards I took it far as I
could it asked me to prepare & encode the PAYLOAD etc. I did those 4 steps.
Why after generating a public/private rsa keypair, Still not able to ssh access the server - root@192.168.6.2: Permission denied (publickey,password)
I input the generated key it asked for with no luck, blank no luck, also foobar1 didn't work nor the combo of (publickey&password)just to try.
I have attempted; ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@192.168.6.2 (doesn't work keeps asking for password)
The very last part at bottom has me perplexed! how would I write it? Can someone plz provide clarity/guidance to resolve it.
I have provided the entire step by step procedure on terminal to see as follows:

```
root@kali:~# ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): /root/.ssh/id_rsa
/root/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
root@kali:~# ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): /root/.ssh/id_rsa
/root/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:ITXrnZAcR6qxTYk1RMy6YJMJKOXWe6YBEHlKg+bc5O0 root@kali
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 3072]----+
|+=.    =O.o      |
|=*oo   =oX       |
|*oO.oo+.X        |
|.+ +*o.O + .     |
|   .+o=.S o      |
|     E.          |
|    .            |
|                 |
|                 |
+----[SHA256]-----+
root@kali:~# ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@192.168.6.2
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
root@192.168.6.2's password: 

Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.168.6.2's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.168.6.2's password: 
root@192.168.6.2: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

**(I TRIED KEY DOESN'T WORK, ALSO BLANK DOESN'T WORK)**